# My touchpad is not working properly in ubuntu 16.04 but there is no problem in older version

Tags: 14.04, touchpad

I am unable to select multiple folders. When I left click and scroll on touchpad the cursor doesn't move it just function as right click. But right click is working properly.
But on my earlier version of ubuntu 16.04 everything worked.